# Linuxコマンドの出力をファイルに行いたい

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, ファイル入出力

以下のコマンドを実行すると、指定したディレクトリ下に存在する全てのファイルのサイズを標準出力できます。

```
find . | xargs wc -c
```

ファイルに出力しようと思い、実行したのは以下のコマンドです。

```
find . | xargs wc -c  > file.txt
```

実行した際のエラーは以下です。

```
wc: .: Is a directory
```

Comment: 全ファイルに対する wc -c の結果は file.txt に入っていると思います。質問はなんでしょう? 「エラーも file.txt に入れたい」「エラーが発生しないようにしたい」「エラーが発生してもいいけど画面に出したくない」?

Comment: エラーが発生しないようにするにはどうしたらいいでしょうか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `wc` コマンドは **ファイル** の情報を取得するコマンドです。
- `find .` で実行すると、ファイルと **ディレクトリ** の一覧が表示されます。

今回の場合であれば、以下の様に find で **ファイルのみ** を検索するようオプション指定するのが一つの方法かと思います。

```
find . -type f | xargs wc -c > file.txt
```